# Using init hook for register_taxonomy is causing invalid_taxonomy in wp_insert_term()

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, hooks, actions

I'm developing a plugin and I've problem with inserting new term to my custom taxonomy.

```
<?php

add_action('init', 'create_tax', 0);
function create_tax()
{
    $args = array(...);
    register_taxonomy('custom_tax', array('post'), $args);
}
// I need this function, so I can use it anywhere in my theme & plugin.
function add_new_term($name)
{
    $result = wp_insert_term($name, 'custom_tax', array('parent'=>0) );
    var_dump($result);
}
add_new_term('Test Term');
```

And the result :

```
object(WP_Error)#159 (2) { ["errors":"WP_Error":private]=> array(1) { ["invalid_taxonomy"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Invalid taxonomy" } } ["error_data":"WP_Error":private]=> array(0) { } }
```

So it's mean `wp_insert_term` executed **before** `register_taxonomy` . So I hooked `create_tax` to *after_setup_theme* instead of *init* just for testing. Nothing changed. Finally I've wrapped `wp_insert_term()` with a function and hooked it to **wp_loaded** action. But as you can image, it's not possible to put all taxonomy related functions (like wp_insert_term, wp_list_categories ...) to **wp_loaded**.

And here is the question,

Which hook should I use for `register_taxonomy`? Because `init` hook is too late for registering taxonomies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting a term into a custom taxonomy](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163541/inserting-a-term-into-a-custom-taxonomy)

Comment: @PieterGoosen actually they are not the same question, because in that question he want to add terms for one time. I mean he want to create a taxonomy and insert 2 default terms to on plugin activation.Because of this, he is using `register_activation_hook()`. But I'll use `wp_insert_term` lots of this, for example there will be a button and everytime  it clicked I'll add a new term to taxonomy.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I put my create_tax method to plugin activation function (and disabled&enabled plugin) , but still same error . Here my codes : http://paste.ubuntu.com/10714681/

Comment: `register_taxonomy` should always be hooked to `init`. If the code in the linked post which I marked duplicate is not working, then you have a serious issue with a plugin or with your theme itself. I personally run that function from a plugin which is where that code should be. Check [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/181979/31545) on how to debug the issue. This answer in this linked question should apply here as well

Comment: @PieterGoosen I think you misunderstood my comment. There is a big difference between my problem and that question. In that question it's registering 2 terms on plugin activation, but I need to register terms whenever I need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert your term *after* the `init` hook (i.e. when the taxonomy is registered):

```
function create_tax()
{
    $args = array(...);
    register_taxonomy('custom_tax', array('post'), $args);

    // Now we're safe
    $result = wp_insert_term('Test Term', 'custom_tax', array('parent'=>0) ); 
}
```

Comment: Just edited first code sample and wrapper `wp_insert_term` with `add_new_term()` function. Can you check please? I need to put it inside of a function because I have a button on my plugin page , when user click to this button I will add a new term to taxonomy . I'll use AJAX request for this and I'll call add_new_term() function inside AJAX method.

Comment: You're still calling `add_new_term` too early - it has to run after `init`. Implement your AJAX handler with the [API](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and it'll work.

Comment: If I don't want to use AJAX , are there any action to achieve this? If there isn't I'll use ajax.

Comment: Of course. Any hook later than `init`. Give me an example of how/when you need to add the term and I'll suggest a hook.